# How to change yii config file via a module

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Is it possible to change config file via a module in Yii ?

I want to add some items to module array in config/main.php

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create file in `protected/modules/moduleName/config/main.php` with such a content

```
<?php
 return array(
      'components'=>array(
      ....
      ),
      'title'=>'My module News'
);
```

And it will be fetched automatically.